# Datepicker is not working on first click of dynamic element

Tags: jquery

jQuery datepicker is not working on first click, while re initiating the script for dynamically appended input field!!! any solutions ?

```
// datepicker click event function reinitiated for dynamically added input field - script       
$(document).on("click", ".datepicker", function (evt) {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        timepicker: false,
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: which is the plugin used?

Comment: @ArunPJohny the properties and method name would indicate jQueryUI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `datetimepicker`? jQuery UI have `datepicker`, isn't it?

Comment: @ArunPJohny good point. I obviously need better glasses.

Comment: ArunPJohny:  it datetimepicker plugin, i used for datepicker in some places and datetimepicker in another places...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic here is not quite right. You should initialise the datepicker on page load, not on click of the element:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        timepicker: false,
    });
});
```

If you need to intialise it on dynamic elements, do so in the callback where they are created:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#bar').html(data).find('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            timepicker: false,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what is the id bar represent, instead can i write my parent id ?

Comment: I've just used `#bar` as an example. You would need to change that to fit your logic.

Comment: I have like this on my ready function, still it not working any suggestions ? $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'customView-Step2.html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                timepicker: false,
            });
        }
    });
});